# Is there a respectable copy of Nāgārjuna's Mūlamadhyamakakārikā in Sanskrit online?

Tags: reference-request, buddhism

I've browsed the net - and couldn't find one. Can someone point me to one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three Sanskrit editions freely available.

[Here](http://fiindolo.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/6_sastra/3_phil/buddh/nagmmk_u.htm) is the J.W. de Jong edition; [here](http://www.dsbcproject.org/node/8237) is the P.L. Vaidya edition; and [here](https://www2.hf.uio.no/polyglotta/index.php?page=fulltext&vid=27&view=fulltext) is the edition by Louis de Vallée-Poussin.

The difference between them are minor.

Comment: Are there glossaries available? - the online Monier-William dictionaries are pretty heavy-duty.

Comment: These are using transliteration schemes - do you know of one using devnagari?

Comment: I don't know of any online edition in devanagari-- since Sanskrit has no script, it must be written using the local alphabet, and most Western scholars use IAST for Romanization.  As for glossaries, there is an ongoing project where someone is translating the MMK one verse at a time, explaining the Sanskrit, which can be found here: http://middleway-verses.blogspot.no/

Comment: @MoziburUllah: If you prefer Devanagari, it is quite straightforward to use an online transliteration tool to convert IAST to Devanagari, such as for instance ["Sanscript"](http://www.learnsanskrit.org/tools/sanscript).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Thanks for the suggestion, I would!